# Как хранить различные параметры для объекта?

Tags: java, база-данных, классы

Очень нужен совет. Я создаю несколько объектов класса `MyClass`.

```
public class MyClass {
    enable(Params params) {
        // Логика. Выполнение, которой зависит от содержания переменной `params`
    }
}
```

Далее мне нужно для каждого объекта запустить метод `enable(Params params)` при этом передать каждому методу различные реализации класса `Params`. Т.е. набор полей у объектов `params` для каждого метода `enable(Params params)` будет разный. Делаю это для того, чтобы организовать гибкое выполнение метода, в зависимости от передаваемых параметров.

Экземпляры класса `MyClass` я храню в БД.

Собственно вопрос. Как мне хранить экземпляр класса `Params` в БД. Чтобы я мог обратившись в БД, запустить экземпляры класса `MyClass` со своими уникальными параметрами? Сложность в том, что создать одну таблицу для хранения объектов `Params` не получится, т.к. поля у объектов реализующих `Params` будут разные.

В данном случае как вариант вижу - сохранять в БД сериализацию объекта `Params`. Помогите советом как в такой ситуации правильно организовать хранение данных.

(Использую Spring и Hibernate. Может я упускаю уже готовые решения для такого рода проблем)
Спасибо!

Comment: Если кол-во полей у Params конечное и разумное, то можете хранить все в одной таблице где отсутствующие поля будут `null`, например

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Количество полей и их наименование будет различное. Т.е. различные реализации родительского класса `Params`

Comment: Т.е. вы заранее не можете составить список всех возможных полей?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб дело в том, что реализации Params будут иметь разные поля. Я могу составить список полей на текущий момент, но новая реализация Param может добавить новые поля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 таблицы:

```
|------MyClass-----|                  
| idClass          |  
| idParams         |     
| ....             |              
|------------------|               
       |
  ссылается на 
       ↓
|---Params--|            |--ParamsRel----|             |---Param--|
|  idParams |            |  idParams(PK) |             |  idParam |
|           |   ←------  |  idParam(PK)  |   -------→  |          |
|           |            |               |             | ...      |
| ....      |            |  ...          |             |----------|
|-----------|            |---------------|
```

В таблицу `MyClass` какие-то постоянные поля. Таблица Params содержит запись, по которой связывается MyClass и динамичные параметры.

В `Param` хранятся все возможные типы параметров.

В `ParamsRel` связь между `Params` и конкретными параметрами.

В принципе, можно убрать таблицу `Params`, а в `ParamsRel` сделать связь между параметрами и `MyClass` напрямую.